# pass values from view to a mehod in controller in mvc asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have 2 views and one method within Controller. This method will be called for each views. 
I need to know how to write a condition within this method to determine whether view 1 or view 2 executed. is there any possible way that i can declare some variable or use viewstate/session (or something like that ) within the view1(viewstate=1) and view2(viewstate=2) and check that value of variable or viewstate within method in controller.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've got no idea what it's the actual context and the conditions that dictate which view should be rendered. How to pass the condition? Well, it depends on the condition itself, the condition must be based on something...where is this something coming from?

1- Coming from a business logic and or database...

```
public ActionResult ActionMethod()
{
     bool condition = BusinessLogicFactory.GetCondition();

    if(condition)
        return View("View1");
    else
        return View("View2");
}
```

2- Provided in the request context...

```
public ActionResult ActionMethod(bool condition)
{
    if(condition)
        return View("View1");
    else
        return View("View2");
}
```

Try avoid session if not needed